# Interchange location of y and z axis in a 3D plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis, matplotlib-3d

By default, plotting a set of points (or whatever) in 3D with `matplotlib`, locates the `z` axis vertically, as seen here (code below):

[image]

I need to interchange the `z` and `y` axis, so that that `y` axis is shown vertically.

I've looked around but found no way to tell `matplotlib` to do this.

**Add:** I do not want to have to resort to a hack where I interchange the data and labels. This is a simple 3 points 3D plot, but I have to plot much more complicated surfaces. I'm looking for a *general* solution, not just something that works with scatter plots. A simple way to tell `matplotlib` to put the `y` axis vertically instead of the `z` axis is the *clean* way to do it.

---

**MWE**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D


fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)

ax.scatter([0.2, 0.5, 0.8], [2.3, 0.47, 1.], [2.1, 5.3, 0.7])

ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')
plt.show()
```

Comment: have you looked into the `zdir` argument to [`scatter`](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.Axes3D.scatter)?

Comment: I' m not familiar with the argument @tom. Keep in mind that I'm looking for a *general* solution, not just something that works on scatter plots.

Comment: `zdir` seems to be available in most 3D plots.

Comment: I have not used `zdir` before, would you like to post an answer?

Comment: too busy right now, maybe if I get time later :)

Comment: @Gabriel: Did you find a working solution? I'm having quite the same problem right now.

Comment: Sadly, no @t.rathjen. The closest solution is the answer provided by innoSPG below.

Comment: I'm also looking for a solution different from the hack. any updates no this?

Comment: @martinako nope, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matplotlib 3.6.0 is now out, and allows you to set this third view angle via the command `ax.view_init(elev, azim, roll)`. See [the official documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.6.0/api/toolkits/mplot3d/view_angles.html#toolkit-mplot3d-view-angles).

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I don't think that this is currently possible. `ax.view_init()` would need to accept a third angle too.
I opened an issue over at github, https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/14453#issue-452397120, let's hope someone is committed to implement this feature.

**Update**

The third view angle was recently implemented and has been merged into the matplotlib main branch: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/21426

It should appear in Matplotlib 3.6.0.

Comment: Thank you for opening the bug report Bastian!

Comment: This was a fun feature to implement, hope you all find it useful!

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is to interchange the position of y and z in the data and label accordingly. instead of

```
ax.scatter([0.2, 0.5, 0.8], [2.3, 0.47, 1.], [2.1, 5.3, 0.7])
```

use

```
ax.scatter([0.2, 0.5, 0.8], [2.1, 5.3, 0.7], [2.3, 0.47, 1.])
```

and label as `ax.set_ylabel('z')` and `ax.set_zlabel('y')`

Comment: Thanks inno, but this type of hack is precisely what I *don't* want to do. I'll add this to the question since it wasn't clear.