# How to change the mouse interaction style for Matplotlib 3d rotation (mplot3d)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I plotted a 3D plot and used `quiver` to plot x, y and z axis.

In matplotlib's interactive plot, I can drag and rotate the 3D plot, but there is one issue:

it seems that the Z-axis is restricted to a plane when I drag the plot. No matter how I drag the plot, Z-axis can only 
rotate in a limited manner(in a plane), while X-axis and Y-axis can be rotated freely.

My question is: is this a limitation of matplotlib or is there any method that I can configure how x, y
and z-axis can be rotated?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

A mininum reproducible example is attached for reference:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


n_radii = 8
n_angles = 36

# Make radii and angles spaces (radius r=0 omitted to eliminate duplication).
radii = np.linspace(0.125, 1.0, n_radii)
angles = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, n_angles, endpoint=False)

# Repeat all angles for each radius.
angles = np.repeat(angles[..., np.newaxis], n_radii, axis=1)

# Convert polar (radii, angles) coords to cartesian (x, y) coords.
# (0, 0) is manually added at this stage,  so there will be no duplicate
# points in the (x, y) plane.
x = np.append(0, (radii*np.cos(angles)).flatten())
y = np.append(0, (radii*np.sin(angles)).flatten())

# Compute z to make the pringle surface.
z = np.sin(-x*y)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

ax.plot_trisurf(x, y, z, linewidth=0.2, antialiased=True)

steps = 100
theta = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, steps)
r_max = 1.2
x = np.zeros_like(theta)
y = r_max * np.cos(theta)
z = r_max * np.sin(theta)
ax.plot(x, y, z, 'r')
ax.plot(y, x, z, 'g')
ax.plot(z, y, x, 'b')

scale = 1.08
ax.quiver((0,), (0), (0), 
          (0), (0), (r_max), color=('c'))
ax.text(0, 0, r_max * scale, 'Z Theta', weight='bold')

ax.quiver((0), (0), (0), 
          (0), (r_max), (0), color=('m'))
ax.text(0, r_max * scale, 0, 'Y', weight='bold')

ax.quiver((0), (0), (0), 
          (r_max), (0), (0), color=('y'))
ax.text(r_max * scale, 0, 0, 'X', weight='bold')


plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57461819/7919597

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34981479/rotating-the-z-axis-in-matplotlib-3d-figure

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38326983/how-to-rotate-a-3d-surface-in-matplotlib

Comment: I see what you mean, and for example in Blender or Mayavi you can change the rotation style. https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkInteractorStyle.html But I could not find out how this works with Matplotlib.

Comment: @Joe, Thank you for the help. Do you have suggestions how to configure it in Matplotlib?

Comment: My suggestion is the first link I sent: Try not to use Matplotlib for 3d. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

My first recommendation is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57459882/how-can-i-connect-scatter-points-in-a-3d-space/57461819#57461819).

But if that is not possible at all, I found a solution that could work.

The method [`_on_move`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py#L1159) in `Axes3D`responsible for processing the mouse events and rotating the plot.

As you can see this function only thinks in azimuth and elevation. That`s why it behaves the way it does.

It is possible to re-bind the default `_on_move` as seen in the method [`mouse_init()`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py#L988) which is called in the constructor of `Axes3D`.

Say our custom mouse interaction style is defined in

```
def _my_on_move(self, event):
    print('my custom mouse style', event)
```

This does not work:

```
ax._on_move = _my_on_move
```

because `_my_on_move` is a function but we need it to be a bound method so the `self` is available.
The solution is to bind the function as method, this is described in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972/adding-a-method-to-an-existing-object-instance):

```
import types
ax._on_move = types.MethodType(_my_on_move, ax)
```

and re-run the mouse initialization:

```
ax.mouse_init()
```

This part in the original `_on_move` will set `elev` and `azim` which are then used by `get_proj()` to set the 
transformation matrix used in `figure.canvas.draw_idle()`:

```
self.elev = art3d._norm_angle(self.elev - (dy/h)*180)
self.azim = art3d._norm_angle(self.azim - (dx/w)*180)
self.get_proj() 
self.figure.canvas.draw_idle()
```

Somehow we have to sneak in a modified transformation matrix. I am not sure if there is a better way, 
but we could just pass in modified values for `elev` and `azim`.

Since we want something smarter we should switch to quaternions. 
I recommend using [transformations.py](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/code/transformations.py.html)
but there is also a module called `mathutils` from Blender with works fine.

Now to the fun part:

You have to get the current view (the current transformation matrix) and 
rotate it based on the mouse movement. Then extract the equivalent `elev` and `azim`
from the rotated matrix. Fun task, some math, but it should be possible.

But I will leave that for to someone else :)

Maybe there is some inspitation found in VTK`s [interactors](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkInteractorStyle.html) or the ones from Blender.

If you want to try the interactors from Mayavi / VTK:

`pip install mayavi` (or `pip3 install mayavi` depending on your version and your virtual environment).

Then run

```
from mayavi import mlab
from tvtk.api import tvtk

for i in [tvtk.InteractorStyleTerrain(),
          tvtk.InteractorStyleJoystickActor(),
          tvtk.InteractorStyleTrackballActor(),
          tvtk.InteractorStyleTrackball()]:

    mlab.test_surf()
    fig = mlab.gcf()
    fig.scene.interactor.interactor_style = i
    mlab.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing this view angle programmatically is possible as of Matplotlib 3.6.0 with the addition of a third "roll" angle, see: https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/prev_whats_new/whats_new_3.6.0.html#d-plots-gained-a-3rd-roll-viewing-angle

However interactive rotation with the mouse is still limited to changing only azimuth and elevation. There is an issue here to talk about other ways to do this: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/26492